# Ignite scalability with Number of nodes

Tags: grid, ignite, in-memory

I was trying to understand how Ignite scaled with the number of nodes on a grid. Has anyone ran tests. How many engines can participate to a grid before downgrading the performance significantly?

Answer (score 0):

Ignite is all about scalability, however it's hard to run any kind of generic test, because it always depends on the use case. Ignite is proven to provide linear or almost linear performance improvement when application code is implemented correctly. As for cluster sizes, there is no theoretical limit, you can as many nodes as you need. There are examples of the cluster of up to 1500 nodes.